# Aggregating by unique identifier and concatenating related values into a string

Tags: r, concatenation, aggregate

I have a need that I imagine could be satisfied by `aggregate` or `reshape`, but I can't quite figure out.

I have a list of names (`brand`), and accompanying ID number (`id`).  This data is in long form, so names can have multiple ID's.  I'd like to de-dupicate by the name (`brand`) and concatenate the multiple possible `id`'s into a string separated by a comment.

For example:

```
brand            id 
RadioShack       2308
Rag & Bone       4466
Ragu             1830
Ragu             4518
Ralph Lauren     1638
Ralph Lauren     2719
Ralph Lauren     2720
Ralph Lauren     2721
Ralph Lauren     2722
```

should become:

```
RadioShack       2308
Rag & Bone       4466
Ragu             1830,4518
Ralph Lauren     1638,2719,2720,2721,2722
```

How would I accomplish this?

Comment: In your desired output, "Ragu" should not appear twice, right?

Comment: For each brand, do you want the result to be a `list` of ids, or a single string pated together?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Let's call your data.frame `DF`

```
> aggregate(id ~ brand, data = DF, c)
         brand                           id
1   RadioShack                         2308
2   Rag & Bone                         4466
3         Ragu                   1830, 4518
4 Ralph Lauren 1638, 2719, 2720, 2721, 2722
```

Another alternative using `aggregate` is:

```
result <- aggregate(id ~ brand, data = DF, paste, collapse = ",")
```

This produces the same result and now `id` is not a `list` anymore. Thanks to @Frank comment. To see the `class` of each column try:

```
> sapply(result, class)
      brand          id 
   "factor" "character"
```

As mentioned by @DavidArenburg in the comments, another alternative is using the `toString` function:

```
aggregate(id ~ brand, data = DF, toString)
```

Comment: Very strangely, R isn't letting me output this data.frame...I think because the `id` is a list.  How do I export to a CSV?

Comment: @Jilber the class of your "id" output column should be "character" (not list), I think, since the OP wants to export the data frame.

Comment: +1. I like this solution as-is for my own use. I think you might want to change it to `aggregate(id~brand,paste,collapse=",",data=df)` or similar for the OP's question, though.

Comment: Worth mentioning `aggregate(id ~ brand, DF, toString)` too probably

Comment: What happen if I want do the same but only for specific value?. I mean, in your example only with `id==2308`.

Comment: I used a similar approach, but it adds an extra space after comma. Is there a specific reason for that?

Comment: Is there a way to aggregate while also only counting unique values? I have tried something like this but it does not work: aggregate(id ~ brand, data = DF, set)

Comment: This seems to work: aggregate(id ~ brand, data = DF, unique)

Answer (score 46):

A nice clean one line in `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DF)
```

#### TWO OPTIONS:

**results as a list**

```
DF[ , .(id = list(id)), by = brand]
          brand                       id
1:   RadioShack                     2308
2:   Rag & Bone                     4466
3:         Ragu                1830,4518
4: Ralph Lauren 1638,2719,2720,2721,2722
>
```

**results as a string**

```
DF[ , .(id = paste(id, collapse=",")), by = brand]
          brand                       id
1:   RadioShack                     2308
2:   Rag & Bone                     4466
3:         Ragu                1830,4518
4: Ralph Lauren 1638,2719,2720,2721,2722
```

---

### Note

**Even though the two results *appear* the same (that is when you print them, they  look identical), they are in fact very different and allow for different functionality.**

Namely, using the list option (the first one) allows you to then perform functions on the orignal `id`s.

The latter will allow you to display the information more easily (including exporting to `CSV` or `excel`), but to operate on the `id`'s will require splicing them back.

Comment: Thanks! list(list(id)) works, but why?

Comment: @LauriK, `list(list(id))` is the same as the first option in the answer. The only difference being the name in the list being explicitly given or not. The outter `list`, data.table will translate into meaning "column" (as all data.tables and data.frames are really just a list of columns).  The inner `list` indicates that the value in each cell will be a list

Comment: Thanks! I was using `paste(id, sep = ",")` and ending up with unaggregated results. It turns out, I needed to use `paste(id, collapse = ",")` instead.

Answer (score 32):

Or using [dplyr](http://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/introduction.html):

```
library(dplyr)
DF %>%
  group_by(brand) %>%
  summarise(id = paste(id, collapse = ","))
```

Where `DF` is the name of your data.frame.

Comment: This will make the summarized columns a comma separated string type.. Not a vector...

Comment: No, just as in the other answers the result is a data.frame, with a vector called `id` of class `character` containing the strings of `id`, separated by commas as desired in the question.  `is.vector(DF$id)` returns `TRUE`.  If you have a question about this approach, consider posting it as a new question.

Comment: library(dplyr)
DFNew<-DF%>% group_by(brand) %>% summarize(id=unique(list(id)))

This worked for me

Comment: @SamFirke, could you please advise how I can use your solution for only pasting unique values of `id` while there are duplicates values of `id` corresponding to a `brand`? Thanks!

Comment: Try adding `unique`, making it `paste(unique(id), collapse = ",")` - if that doesn't do it, it merits posting a new question.

Answer (score 11):

Here's the information in base R:

```
myby <- by(df$id,df$brand,function(x)paste(x,collapse=","))
```

The formatting of "by" objects is weird. You can take `data.frame(id=c(myby))` and the brands will become rownames:

```
#                                    id
# RadioShack                       2308
# Rag & Bone                       4466
# Ragu                        1830,4518
# Ralph Lauren 1638,2719,2720,2721,2722
```

Alternately, if you load the `data.table` package, this will work:

```
dt <- data.table(df)
dt[,paste(id,collapse=","),by=brand]
#           brand                       V1
# 1:   RadioShack                     2308
# 2:   Rag & Bone                     4466
# 3:         Ragu                1830,4518
# 4: Ralph Lauren 1638,2719,2720,2721,2722
```