# Aggregate rows with a common value retaining unique values

Tags: r, aggregate

I've tried to do the following starting from this data frame

```
    Chr                Gene.Symbols
2  chr1                       GSTM1
3  chr2                     MIR4432
4  chr2                      BCL11A
5  chr2                      PAPOLG
6  chr2                   LINC01185
7  chr2                   LINC01185
8  chr2              LINC01185, REL
9  chr2                         REL
10 chr2                         REL
11 chr2                         REL
12 chr2                         REL
13 chr2                            
14 chr2                       PUS10
15 chr2             PEX13, KIAA1841
```

I would like to have this result:

```
    Chr             Gene.Symbols
2  chr1             GSTM1
3  chr2             MIR4432,BCL11A,PAPOLG,LINC01185,REL,PUS10,PEX13,KIAA1841
```

I've managed to aggregate the gene symbols together using:

```
aggregate(Gene.Symbols~Chr, data, paste, collapse = ",")
```

that I learned from other questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16596515/aggregating-by-unique-identifier-and-concatenating-related-values-into-a-string?noredirect=1&lq=1), but I wasn't able to remove duplicates.

Can someone help me, please?

**UPDATE:**
I also need a file with only the genes names one per row (without the "Chr" column). How can I traspose the gene names?
I am starting now with a file with as many rows as Chr and each row one has several genes in the Gene.Symbols column.

Comment: in row 8 , `LINC01185, REL` or `LINC01185`, also in row 15 `PEX13, KIAA1841` or `PEX13`

Comment: @Sotos I think the question is a little bit different from the 'duplicated' one

Comment: @Wen Hmm...I just noticed `LINC01185, REL` and also `REL`. You are right, I will reopen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even another option:

```
library(splitstackshape) # automatically loads the 'data.table'-package
cSplit(mydf, 'Gene.Symbols', sep = ','
       , direction = 'long')[, .(Gene.Symbols = toString(unique(Gene.Symbols)))
                             , by = Chr]
```

which gives:

> ```
>     Chr                                                    Gene.Symbols
> 1: chr1                                                           GSTM1
> 2: chr2 MIR4432, BCL11A, PAPOLG, LINC01185, REL, PUS10, PEX13, KIAA1841
> ```

Answer (score 3):

An idea via base R in two steps,

```
dd <- aggregate(Gene.Symbols ~ Chr, df, paste, collapse = ', ')

dd$Gene.Symbols <- sapply(strsplit(dd$Gene.Symbols, ", "), function(i) 
                                                    paste(unique(i), collapse = ","))
```

which gives,

```
#   Chr                                              Gene.Symbols
#1 chr1                                                     GSTM1
#2 chr2 MIR4432,BCL11A,PAPOLG,LINC01185,REL,,PUS10,PEX13,KIAA1841
```

A one-liner (compliments of @Cath) would be,

```
aggregate(Gene.Symbols ~ Chr, df, function(gene) 
                              paste(unique(unlist(strsplit(gene, ", "))), collapse = ','))
```

Comment: I tried the two steps but I keep having some duplicates

`Chr                                                             Gene.Symbols
2 chr2      MIR4432, BCL11A, PAPOLG, LINC01185,  REL, REL, , PUS10, PEX13,  KIAA1841`

Comment: @FrancescaScellato wrong delimiter. It should be `", "`.

Comment: to avoid `sapply` step, you can directly do: `aggregate(Gene.Symbols ~ Chr, df, function(gene) paste(unique(unlist(strsplit(gene, ", "))), collapse = ','))`

Answer (score 2):

```
collapse_unique <- function(x) {
    paste(unique(x), collapse = ",")
}

aggregate(Gene.Symbols~Chr, data, collapse_unique)
```

Answer (score 2):

By using `dplyr` and `tidyr`

```
#1st unnest your string
df=df %>%
    transform( Gene.Symbols = strsplit( Gene.Symbols, ",")) %>%
    unnest( Gene.Symbols)
# then group by 
df%>%group_by(Chr)%>%summarise(Gene.Symbols=toString(unique(Gene.Symbols)))

# A tibble: 2 x 2
    Chr                                                           Gene.Symbols
  <chr>                                                                  <chr>
1  chr1                                                                  GSTM1
2  chr2       MIR4432, BCL11A, PAPOLG, LINC01185, REL, PUS10, PEX13,  KIAA1841
```